# Why would a web page be blank even if the source was identical to a web page that isn't blank?

Tags: php, html, sql-server, apache

I have a page on a server at a remote location that only displays if it is accessed internally.

Here's how it works, the page has a button and a list of files, when the button is clicked the script creates a csv file from various database tables and writes it to a folder on the server.  The page then refreshes with the new file in the list.

On the server this is fine but when I access the site externally I have the following problem:

- Clicking the button causes the script to run, so far so good.
- The page is blank on refresh.
- The source for the page however, is identical to that of the page source when loaded correctly on the server.
- The file is created so it can't be a folder permissions thing.

Any ideas?

Unfortunately I can't give you any code, it's work related and we don't share. This is as far as it gets:

```
<body>
        <script language="Javascript">
            function titleBar_Dis
```

Comment: If you refresh the page does it come back? Viewing the source in many browsers actually makes a new page request, it doesn't always show you the source of what you're *currently* viewing. If so, you may have an error in your script after clicking the button.

Comment: Just about everyone posting here is using code from work. Please consider posting redacted versions of the relevant parts of your work ... it's just wild guesses without that info.

Comment: refreshing takes you back to the login page no matter where you are in the system.

Comment: @Dai and is the source you're viewing that of the login page? Do you have errors enabled? Have you checked the php error log? Can you view the rendered source?

Comment: no, its the source of the export page.  I just did an 'inspect element' instead of a view source and it just shows an error which I'm about to try and trace so thanks for the tip about viewing source not being reliable.

Comment: heres the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'attachEvent'

Unfortnately that file has no javascript so I have to dig through a mountain of includes.

Comment: Dai, you can always give code without compromising your work policies, just remove whatever it's sensitive. It's not like you're inventing the wheel anyway...

Comment: Glad you were able to work it out :)

Folks here can be extremely helpful, but there's an expectation that you'll post some examples of the code you've tried, error logs, etc.  

Check around some of the other posts for examples of how others post company code without letting out sensitive info. Unfortunately, there's not much someone can do without that ...

Comment: I'd recommend this old question is closed or deleted. Without a [mcve], it isn't going to be useful to any future readers. Would you consider removing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given us much to go on.

I would suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to view the requests both times. Hopefully you will see something different.

If not does this happen in all browsers or is it a browser specific thing?

Comment: Thanks, the response in fiddler shows that the page stopped being delivered mid sentence about 2 lines below the <body> tag...

Answer (score 1):

It will help quite a bit if you edit the post with some samples of the code you've tried. Sometimes a helper can spot problems that you didn't notice.

My first guess would be that your JavaScript references internal URLs (e.g http://our-server.internal/lan) that don't work correctly when you're accessing them from outside.

But, that's just a shot in the dark based on your description. Seeing some code would make this a lot easier.

Comment: I can't show any code because the whole thing is a company secret, you know how it is.

Answer (score 0):

The Page's body could be hidden using JavaScript, check the included scripts, or remove all scripts from the page that is blank. The page might give errors afterwards, but at least then you have some direction

Comment: Since the javascript is identical in all our instances it is very unlikely that it is causing the problem, the javascript error appears on closer inspection to occur on every single page without any negative impact.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It appears that this is a network problem and not a code problem.